# is it possible to get an ios device token without installing the app?

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, mdm, devicetoken

I want to manage certain iOs devices. I don't want to install any app on the device. I read that I can create configuration profile with MDM payload and install on device. I then somehow need to get the device token and then use Java APNS to start pushing notification to the devices.

Is this possible or do I need an app installed on the device which will send the device token to the server?

Is there an example or tutorial that details how to do it without the app installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it using a profile